# Improve function that cleans non printing and other ASCII characters

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an Excel 2013 Workbook with sheets imported from various sources.

These contain *Unicode* characters all over the place which the clean function do not account for.

I found a function which works cell by cell, but I'd like to have it used on a range of cells instead of having to put the function in each cell individually.

Could someone please help me convert this function?

Thank you

```
  Function CleanTrim(ByVal S As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String
  Dim X As Long, CodesToClean As Variant
  CodesToClean = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, _
                       21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)

  If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then S = Replace(S, Chr(160), " ")
  For X = LBound(CodesToClean) To UBound(CodesToClean)
    If InStr(S, Chr(CodesToClean(X))) Then S = Replace(S, Chr(CodesToClean(X)), "")
  Next
  CleanTrim = WorksheetFunction.Trim(S)

'Call function == use CleanTrim just like it was a built-in Excel function. For example, =CleanTrim(B2)
End Function
```

Comment: It will need to be a sub and cannot be called like a formula on the sheet.

Comment: On a side note, this function does not clean up Unicode. It removes unprintable plus some more ASCII characters from a string, and it does so in a most inefficient way.

Comment: Are the cells in the same location on the imported sheets? If there is consistency then a sub could be written to call the function on the cells. What is the range you want to use it on?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Sub Procedure I wrote which when tested worked.

```
Sub CleanCells()
  Dim x As Long, CodesToClean As Variant
  CodesToClean = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, _
                       21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)

  Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A168")

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        For Each cell In row.Cells
        'Do Something
                S = Replace(S, Chr(160), " ")
                For x = LBound(CodesToClean) To UBound(CodesToClean)
                  If InStr(S, Chr(CodesToClean(x))) Then S = Replace(S, Chr(CodesToClean(x)), "")
                Next
                WorksheetFunction.Trim (S)

        Next cell
    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: You can do the whole range as one,  Look into `Range.Replace`

Answer (score 1):

A `Regexp` will be cleaner.

As a *UDF* below (which could be used in an array)

See https://regex101.com/r/Hdv65h/1

```
Function strClean(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegexp As Object
Set objRegexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegexp
    'hex codes for 0-31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157
    .Pattern = "[\x00-\x1F]|\x7F|\x7F|\x81|\x8D|\x8F|\x90|\x9D"
    .Global = True
    strClean = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```